# printf output convert from one row to number of arguments

Tags: bash, printf

this is part of my code:

```
FCWWN=`fcinfo hba-port | grep HBA | awk '{print $4}'`

for i in ${FCWWN}
do
    FCREMOTE=`fcinfo remote-port -p ${i} | grep Remote | nawk '{print $4}'`
    PRODUCT=`/usr/sbin/luxadm display ${FCREMOTE} | grep Product | nawk -F: '{print $2}'`
    CAPACITY=`/usr/sbin/luxadm display ${FCREMOTE} | grep capacity | nawk -F: '{print $2}'`
    LUNNAME=`/usr/sbin/luxadm display ${FCREMOTE} | grep /dev/rdsk | grep -i -v DEVICE`
    FCSTATE=`fcinfo hba-port ${i} | grep State: | nawk '{print $2}'`
    echo ""
    echo -e The FC Port WWN "\033[1m \E[36;40m ${i} \033[0m is \033[1m \E[37;42m ${FCSTATE} \033[0m"; echo -ne "\E[0m"
    printf "################################################################################## \n"
    printf "%-6s %9s %18s \n" "LUN:" "Storage" "Disk"
    printf "%-6s %9s %18s \n"  " "    "Type"    "Size"
    printf "=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- \n"
    printf "%-6s\n %9s\n %2s\n" "${LUNNAME}" "${PRODUCT}" "${CAPACITY}"
done
```

The output is :

```
The FC Port WWN   10000000c9822976  is   online
##################################################################################
LUN:     Storage               Disk
            Type               Size
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
  /dev/rdsk/c4t60060E80102A8AF005119C37000000C2d0s2
  /dev/rdsk/c4t60060E80102A8AF005119C37000000C0d0s2
  /dev/rdsk/c4t60060E80102A8AF005119C370000016Cd0s2
  /dev/rdsk/c4t60060E80102A8AF005119C3700000028d0s2
  /dev/rdsk/c4t60060E80102A8AF005119C37000000E1d0s2
                DF600F
                DF600F
                DF600F
                DF600F
                DF600F
        131072.000 MBytes
        131072.000 MBytes
        65536.000 MBytes
        262144.000 MBytes
        65536.000 MBytes
```

And the desired output is :

```
The FC Port WWN   10000000c9822976  is   online
##################################################################################
LUN:     Storage               Disk
            Type               Size
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
  /dev/rdsk/c4t60060E80102A8AF005119C37000000C2d0s2   DF600F   131072.000 MBytes
  /dev/rdsk/c4t60060E80102A8AF005119C37000000C0d0s2   DF600F   131072.000 MBytes
  /dev/rdsk/c4t60060E80102A8AF005119C370000016Cd0s2   DF600F    65536.000 MBytes
  /dev/rdsk/c4t60060E80102A8AF005119C3700000028d0s2   DF600F    262144.000 MBytes
  /dev/rdsk/c4t60060E80102A8AF005119C37000000E1d0s2   DF600F    65536.000 MBytes
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Excellent first post. Sample output, sample errors, actual code. Bravo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way is to convert your three multi-line strings to arrays:

```
# bash 4 or later
mapfile -t LUN_ARR <<< "$LUNNAME"
mapfile -t PROD_ARR <<< "$PRODUCT"
mapfile -t CAP_ARR <<< "$CAPACITY"

# bash 3
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a LUN_ARR <<< "$LUNNAME"
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a PROD_ARR <<< "$PRODUCT"
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a CAP_ARR <<< "$CAPACITY"
```

Then simply iterate through the arrays with a C-style loop

```
for (( idx=0; idx < ${#LUN_ARR[@]}; idx++ )); do
    printf "%-40s %9s %s\n" "${LUN_ARR[idx]}" "${PROD_ARR[idx]}" "${CAP_ARR[idx]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. I don't have resources to test, but I really thing this will solve your problem.

not

```
    printf "%-6s\n %9s\n %2s\n" "${LUNNAME}" "${PRODUCT}" "${CAPACITY}"
```

but

```
    printf "%-6s %9s %2s\n" "${LUNNAME}" "${PRODUCT}" "${CAPACITY}"
```

The extra '\n's will always put in a line breaks, right?

Also you could write this as one awk script.

OR at least reduce the number of procesess that you're starting by re-writting the front part of your script like

```
PRODUCT=`/usr/sbin/luxadm display ${FCREMOTE} | nawk -F: '/Product/{print $2}'`
```

And, as you're using nawk, that says solaris to me. Maybe you're writting /bin/sh (bourne shell scripts),
but if not, back-ticks have been deprecated since 1995 (at least). Use modern command-substitution like

```
PRODUCT=$(/usr/sbin/luxadm display ${FCREMOTE} | nawk -F: '/Product/{print $2}')
```

IHTH

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestions. printf "%-6s %9s %2s\n" - the output the same :  /dev/rdsk/c4t60060E80102A8AF005119C37000000E1d0s2             DF600F
                DF600F
                DF600F
                DF600F
                DF600F                  131072.000 MBytes
        131072.000 MBytes